# how to correctly write command inside commands (ssh)?

Tags: bash, ssh

**Here is the command I have which works**

It's just a kill with an expression which returns a number

```
kill $(ps -ef | grep '[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector' | cut -f8 -d' ') &> /dev/null
```

**Here is the ssh I normally use**

```
bash -c 'timeout  120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.XXX "cd NightTest"'
```

**I try to combine both of them**

```
bash -c 'timeout  120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 "kill $(ps -ef | grep '[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector' | cut -f8 -d' ') &> /dev/null"'
```

It doesn't work, my guess is that it gets mixed up with the ''.

**Tried options**

Escaping most of the ' in the kill commands :

```
 bash -c 'timeout  120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 "kill $(ps -ef | grep \'[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector\' | cut -f8 -d\' ') &> /dev/null"'
```

Do not work either, I did many other tries but can't make it work.

Any ideas?

**Added note**

My system doesn't support pkill command

Comment: Why the `bash -c '…'` notation in the first place?  Why not just `timeout …`?  Using the single quotes for the `bash -c '…'` greatly complicates the processing. You need to get a level of single quotes around the command to be executed.

Comment: Your code when you combine both works for me. What do you mean by “it doesn't work”?

Comment: @Arkanosis: the combined version evaluates the `$(ps …)` on the local machine, not on the host you are `ssh`-connecting to.

Comment: thanks a lot! about the -c is because I normally send many command in a string ( command1 && command 2 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `bash -c` notation.  Assuming you don't rewrite the command to use `pkill`, then you need something like:

```
timeout 120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 \
    'kill $(ps -ef | grep "[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector" | cut -f8 -d" ") &> /dev/null'
```

Note that I used double quotes inside the command to be executed.  Fortunately, there was nothing in the command where it would matter whether single quotes or double quotes were used.

The version with 'embedded single quotes' doesn't work because you can't embed single quotes in a single-quoted string.  You can, if you must, write `'…'\''…'` to get a single quote in between two ellipsis.  The first `'` terminates the current single quoted string (even if the preceding character is a backslash; there are no escapes in a single quoted string); the `\'` generates a single quote; the third `'` in the centre group resumes the single quoted string again.

Thus, in your attempt:

```
bash -c 'timeout  120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 "kill $(ps -ef | grep \'[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector\' | cut -f8 -d\' ') &> /dev/null"'
```

the Bash command sees:

```
timeout  120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 "kill $(ps -ef | grep \[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector\ | cut -f8 -d\ ) &> /dev/null"
```

which means `grep` gets multiple arguments where you wanted one, etc.  It completely breaks up the meaning.

Nesting quoting conventions is hard — really hard.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and plus giving an explanation about why what I did didn't work!!

Answer (score 3):

It'd be easier if you use `pkill` to kill the desired process. It performs the searching and killing all in one go.

```
pkill -f 'matchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector'
```

Then you can throw that into the SSH call:

```
bash -c 'timeout 120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 pkill -f "matchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector"'
```

What's the purpose of the `bash -c`, by the way? If you can get rid of that, then it's even simpler.

```
timeout 120s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.155.148 pkill -f 'matchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector'
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! the -c is so command are read from string (because normally I sent lots of command with &&)

Comment: actually in my system it doesn't work, it doesn't have the pkill so I really have to go with the kill command (limited bash)