# Linux bash -c in command shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am using ssh in a shell script in order to go on multiple linux server and get disk information on a particular disk.  I am running following but I am not able to figure out the quote sequencing...In this example I am just capturing the header for my report....

```
ssh dbadmin@myserver bash -c '"df -kh | grep File | awk '{ print \$1 "  |  " \$2 "  |  " \$3 "  |  " \$4 "  |  " \$5 }' | tail -n -1"'
```

and following error...

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: -c: line 0:`df -kh | grep File | awk { print    |      |      |      |    } | tail -n -1'

Any help or suggestions would be great...

Thanks

Comment: Why are you single *and* double quoting the entire command? Why are you using `bash -c` here at all?

Comment: See [How to correctly write command inside commands with `ssh`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893976/) which also uses the `bash -c '...'` idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use quoted here-doc and avoid escaping:

```
ssh -t -t dbadmin@myserver<<'EOF'
df -kh | awk -v OFS="  |  " '/file/{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }' | tail -n -1
EOF
```

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.